# Hosting ASP.NET MVC application on IIS web server using Windows 2019 server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-10, windows-server-2019

[The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.]

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

- The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Most likely causes:

- The worker process is unable to read the applicationhost.config or web.config file.
- There is malformed XML in the applicationhost.config or web.config file.
- The server cannot access the applicationhost.config or web.config file because of incorrect NTFS permissions.

Detailed Error Information:

- Module       DynamicCompressionModule
- Notification     SendResponse
- Handler      ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
- Error Code       0x8007007e
- Physical Path    :
- Logon Method     Anonymous
- Logon User       Anonymous

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAYGn.png)

Even after giving all the permission, application is not running and I am getting the same error everytime as attached with screenshot. I am not able to host it on iis web server using windows 2019 server

Comment: Please try to improve your searching skills. Such has been discussed more than a decade ago and you don’t have to troubleshoot from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code `0x8007007e` translates as `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` (i.e. the specified ‘DynamicCompressionModule’ could not be found).

When WSUS is installed, it adds the XPress compression scheme module (`suscomp.dll`) into IIS. In IIS, Compression Schemes are defined globally and so will attempt to load in every application pool within IIS. As such, it will kick out this error when the 64bit version of `suscomp.dll` attempts to load in an application pool which is running in 32bit mode.

**Fix:**
Disable the XPress compression scheme that was introduced by WSUS from the configuration using the command below:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /-[name='xpress']
```

Running the above command in my 'Command prompt' fixed the issue.